# UI performance with GPS on Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android

## Context

I'm working on an app that displays events in the area and calculates the distance to these events. The idea is that when you move, the distance is updated. I have been succesfully able to get location updates from the location manager in Android, so the basics work.

## Question

I noticed that the UI performance drops badly (low framerates) when I enable GPS and set a treshold of 10 seconds for location updates and a distance treshold of 1KM. I don't think this is normal behavior and I'm wondering what I can do to improve the performance.

## Please note

The app is build using Mono for Android 4.0, but the same problem happens when I rebuild the same activity using Java only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since callbacks are handled on main UI thread, they have potential to slow down your UI.
Solution: provide looper to decouple location data processing and UI handling:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener,%20android.os.Looper%29

Answer (score 1):

Do you use thread to get updated location. if not then use this and use handler to reflect the updated info into UI

Comment: The location manager should be called from a UI thread, so no I'm not using a separate thread to register the location update listener.